# Horizontal scrolling treated as right click in Java applications

Tags: java, touchpad

I've enabled horizontal scrolling for my touchpad in Ubuntu 11.04, but when using it in Java applications (NetBeans in my case) it is instead as a right click.

Horizontal scrolling works perfectly in all applications that are not written in Java.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 4):

That is [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1026063). You can fix it as described there, by running `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0` (two finger scroll will still work fine).

You can add the command at startup with the "startup applications" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Possible workaround was discussed on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9406066) - you either run manually a script to enable or disable the right-click depending upon whether you are using a JAVA based application.

You could - for example, connect each of the scripts as Keyboard Shortcuts e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to enable and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to disable

Create a script called "hscroll_disable" containing:

```
DEVICE_NAME='TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
PROP_NAME='Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes'

xinput set-int-prop "$DEVICE_NAME" "$PROP_NAME" 8 4 5 4 5
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
  zenity --info --text "Horizontal Scrolling Disabled"
else
  zenity --error --text "Error disabling horizontal scroll."
fi
```

Create a script called "hscroll_disable" containing:

```
DEVICE_NAME='TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
PROP_NAME='Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes'

xinput set-int-prop "$DEVICE_NAME" "$PROP_NAME" 8 6 7 4 5
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
  zenity --info --text "Horizontal Scrolling Enabled"
else
  zenity --error --text "Error enabling horizontal scroll."
fi
```

Give both scripts execute permission i.e.

```
chmod +x hscroll_disable
chmod +x hscroll_enable
```

The two important parts of the scripts are "DEVICE_NAME" and "PROP_NAME"

You can find out which device name to use on your system like this:

```
xinput list --short
```

This will give an output similar to:

```
"Virtual core pointer"  id=0    [XPointer]
"Virtual core keyboard" id=1    [XKeyboard]
"ThinkPad Extra Buttons"        id=2    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"  id=3    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"Video Bus"     id=4    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"Macintosh mouse button emulation"      id=5    [XExtensionPointer]
"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" id=6    [XExtensionPointer]
```

Then to find the property-name:

```
xinput list-props "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
```

This will give an output similar to:

```
Device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint':
        Device Enabled (93):            1
        Evdev Axis Inversion (230):             0, 0
        Evdev Reopen Attempts (227):            10
        Evdev Axis Calibration (228):           
        Evdev Axes Swap (229):          0
        Evdev Middle Button Emulation (231):            1
        Evdev Middle Button Timeout (232):              50
        Evdev Wheel Emulation (233):            1
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (234):               6, 7, 4, 5
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (235):            10
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (236):            200
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (237):             2
        Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (238):          0
```

Solution reproduced above from "vace117"